# How to create objects of the BaseClass and link SubClass with it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class and a subclass.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Baseclass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def test():
        pass

class Subclass(Baseclass):
     def test():
         print("test")
```

And another class creating the object of sub_class.

```
class Main():
    def __init(self):
        self.obj = Subclass()
```

I want to create the instance of the Baseclass and link Subclass with it.
How can this be done?
Can it be done using Dependency Injection?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Python automatically "links" (through inheritance) Subclass to Baseclass. Every field and method in Baseclass is accessible to a Subclass instantiation. You probably want to change the `self.obj = Subclass()` to `my_subclass = Subclass`. Then when you run `my_subclass.test()` you will see it print the word "test".

Comment: *I want to create the instance of the Baseclass and link Subclass with it* - what does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

For definition, you can't create an instance of the Baseclass with abstractmethod:

```
class Baseclass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass


Baseclass()
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Baseclass with abstract methods test
```